# FIWARE Orion on VMware "Access forbidden"

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, vmware-player

I have recently instantiated Orion image found [HERE](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker/downloads) on VMware Player. After update to the 0.22 version I can confirm that it is up and running, with curl inside VM:

```
[root@centimeter ~]# curl -XGET localhost:1026/version
<orion>
    <version>0.22.0</version>
    <uptime>0 d, 0 h, 5 m, 54 s</uptime>
    <git_hash>06bc8fd55ee37567a3754422e78e732c8fd69da8</git_hash>
    <compil_time>Mon May 25 13:25:10 CEST 2015</compile_time>
    <compiled_by>fermin</compiled_by>
    <compiled_in>centollo</compiled_in>
</orion>
```

However, if I ran this check from host machine (to IP of guest VM or with port forward set properly), I get this:

```
GET http://192.168.0.104:1026/version
{
    message: "Access forbidden"
}
```

What am I missing?

I have tried curl-ing to this same IP from VM itself with same error. I have set security rules and tried messing with CentOS iptables, but nothing works. I can ping VM's IP from host comp.

My best guess is that it has something to do with recent CORS implemented. Any help?

Thanks,
Dušan

Comment: Thank you Fermin. As you suggested in the response it was a networking problem. At first my network was down when I instantiated VM from image. I found eth0 on different name, so I solved that problem from answers like this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vmware-linux-lost-eth0-after-cloning-image.html. 

However, it seems that then my loopback interface remained down. Simple `ifup lo` solved everything. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to know you have solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Orion process itself is generating that message, as [no place in its source code is able to render that message](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Access%20forbidden).

Thus, it seems that another entity is generating that message. It could be a process running inside the VM, you could check using `netstat -ntlpd | grep 1026` if some other process is listening on 192.168.0.104 interface. Or it could be some networking process related with VMware tooling running outside the VM (although curl-ing to that same IP from VM itself wouldn't support that option...).

In any case, ensure that that 192.168.0.104 IP is associated to that particular VM.